# JAXB mapping 1 XML Tag to 2 variables

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i am trying to use one class to map the response i get from an XML request.
But the xml response differs, depending own some settings. For example in a response i get the tag "owner" which is filled with the ID of the owner object. If i add a setting in my request i will get back the full owner data, like the firstname and lastname. Now i want to map the owner tag to either a String variable or a Class depending on the response.

Example :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "domain")
public class Response {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "owner")
    private String ownerSimple;

    @XmlElement(name = "owner")
    private Owner ownerComplex;

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ownerc")
public class OwnerC {

    @XmlElement
    int id;

    @XmlElement
    String fname;

    @XmlElement
    String lname;
}
```

XML to map :

```
<response>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <owner>1234</owner>  <!-- in this case it's only a id -->
</response>

<response>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <owner>  <!-- in this case it's the owner class -->
        <id>1234</id>
        <fname>Jon</fname>
        <lname>Doe</lname>
    </owner>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` to handle this use case. This annotation allows you to unmarshall any XML to a Java object (DOM `Node`). In a second step,  it is possible to unmarshall the `Node` to the required Object

**Response**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "domain")
public class Response {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    private Object owner;

    private String ownerSimple;

    @XmlTransient
    private Owner ownerComplex;
```

**Owner**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "owner")
public class Owner {

    @XmlElement
    int id;

    @XmlElement
    String fname;

    @XmlElement
    String lname;
```

**Unmarshaller**

```
//Unmarshaller. Step 1 - Decodes Response and set a DOM Node at Owner
//Important. Owner class must not be present in JAXB context, letting next step to decode the object properly. 
//Owner variable at Response class is annotated with @XmlTransient
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Response response = (Response) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

//Unmarshaller. Step 2. Convert Node to the suitable Object
//Considering both cases, simple-> String complex -> Owner Object.      
String ownerSimple = ((Node)response.getOwner()).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
if (ownerSimple != null){
    response.setOwnerSimple(ownerSimple);
} else {
    JAXBContext jaxbContextOwner = JAXBContext.newInstance(Owner.class);
    Unmarshaller  jaxbUnmarshallerOwner = jaxbContextOwner.createUnmarshaller();
    Owner ownerComplex = (Owner) jaxbUnmarshallerOwner.unmarshal((Node)response.getOwner());
    response.setOwnerComplex(ownerComplex);
}

 //Marshaller to system.out. Your object is well mapped in both cases
 Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
 marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
 marshaller.marshal(rx, System.out);
```

Comment: Hey there ! This solution sounds great. I only need to improve one thing. Would it be possible to map the "ownerSimple" to the tag "owner" when i create the output, so the output XML looks the same as the input XML ?

Comment: Hi @inf3ction. The "ownerSimple" tag is not mapped. If you marshall with the provided sample code, it will write at "owner" tag the same content as input in both cases (I have checked it). To provide new content, I think you can set at marshall time the value of "owner" to ownerSimple or ownerComplex in the same way that unmarshalling. Probably you will need to init the `JAXBContext` with Owner.class depending on you are using simple or complex object