# Apache CXF parse WSDL Schema xsd:any type

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am trying to find good and most generic solution for soap web services' problem. The problem I need to solve is to replace proxies which Apache Axis generate using given WSDL file with the proxies that Apache CXF genereta using `wsdl2java` command. 
However, when I generate proxies with CXF and opened the classes in IDE I realised that I have:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
```

element as a Class field. This was strange. I looked at the pure wsdl and in one of the `complextype` properties there is `xsd:any` element. I have been searching for a long time what is the problem and for the best solution to solve it. I found [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Developing_Applications_Using_JAX-WS/files/JAXWSWildAnyTypeMapping.html) . It seems that apache CXF runtime cannot determine the actual data type of the element. So I need to parse it manually with DOM parser.

Apache Axis generate the following:

```
private org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement[] _any;
```

The tag:

```
<any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

My question is: What is the best way to solve this problem? Do I really need DOM parser to ? Is there something that i miss ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`<xsd:any>` is used to allow in the schema any element. See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_any.asp)

> The  element enables us to extend the XML document with elements not specified by the schema.

So mapping of CXF is correct. The JAXB annotation `@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)` means that for that field if contains an element annotated with `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl` then an instance of the corresponding class will be used to populate the field if not the element will be set as an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

See an example [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html)

Comment: But, what if I send request to the server, and it responds me. Then I need to fetch the data and I call. result.getAny(). It will give me object. And then I want to call methods to it, but it is object. Axis cast it to MessageElement. And I can call specific methods to it. In my practice I want to reproduce one of the functionalities of this class, so I need the data in it. I want to convert the element to Document type.

Comment: According to documentation, you can cast the object to `org.w3c.dom.Element`, which will allow you to access DOM structure

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned it in my question. It seem that I have no other choice. Thank you that you tried to help me. I appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help. See also my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38405472/6371459, using JAXB unmarshaller  to map a `<any>` element  in a second step to a Java object (annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. I'm not sure if you can use it